# Grab values from SQL array in PHP with while loop

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops, while-loop

So I have a table in mySQL that holds sale records which have customerID, productPrice, and quantity.  I need to get the cost from each row, and then compile that into a totalCost. I need to use a while loop (assignment instructions) to do so, and so far I have not had any luck. Here is where I am at now, any help is appreciated

```
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($recordSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $cost = $productPrice * $quantity
    $totalCost = $totalCost + $cost
};
echo "$totalCost";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$totalCost = 0;
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($recordSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $cost = $record["productPrice"] * $record["quantity"];
    $totalCost += $cost;
}
echo "$totalCost";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment , but am not cool enough to write one, try putting your $totalcost variable out side of your while loop, that way its value won't be overwritten with each iteration.

```
$totalcost=0;
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($recordSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$cost = $record['productPrice'] * $record['quantity'];
$totalCost = $totalCost + $cost;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$totalCost = 0;
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($recordSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $cost = $record['productPrice'] * $record['quantity'];
    $totalCost += $cost
}
echo "$totalCost";
```

You first need to declare `$totalCost` or else you'll get an undefined error, you don't need to add semi-colons to curly brackets when ending them, and also when you're pulling information using `$record = mysqli_fetch_array($recordSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` you need to access the information as array keys so the price would be `$record['price']`

Answer (score -1):

change

```
$cost = $productPrice * $quantity
```

into

```
$cost = $record["productPrice"] * $record["quantity"];
```

Comment: Why the -1? I'm really curious.

Comment: guess someone didn't like me beating him to the punch.

Comment: I see your answer doesn't entirely solve the problem to the question, but still a valid point.

Comment: No, it does entirely solve the problem. Indeed, not declaring the $productPrice outside the loop will cause a *notice*, but it *will* work. The price will add up, and the echo will show.

Comment: Yeah your right it will add up. But the persitance o the error message isn't a 100% solution